# importing from daz 3d

Tags: import

I'm trying to import a scene from Daz Studio 4.10 . I'm using the diffeomorphic addon and have installed the addon according to the manual:  https://diffeomorphic.blogspot.com/p/daz-importer-version-14.html. However, when I import my daz file, the characters loose their original position. Also, the morphs I applied are lost: the 'children' are quite grown up again. Furthermore, in the rendered viewport, I see nothing but a black contour. 
If someone has some advise, please share!

Many thanks in advance.

[image: the daz scene] 
[image: the imported scene in blender 2.8]

Comment: This may be the addons' fault as on the official Daz  3D website they only mention exporting to Maya.  Did you try an .fbx?

Comment: I thought the daz importer would work at least as well as the fbx method: https://youtu.be/Ia7Tj8tt2Vw

Comment: Moreover, the website on which I downloaded the addon states that "the DAZ importer is a tool for importing native DAZ Studio files (DAZ User File *.duf, DAZ System File *.dsf) into Blender".

Comment: If it was as this site says, you shouldn't have had any problems. And maybe the plug-ins latest version is required or you need to configure it before using.

Comment: unfortunately I do have problems...: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/153487/importing-from-daz-studio

Answer (score 0):

You will have to formally set up your scene in Blender just like you did in DAZ- but there are benefits to doing this, such as access to Blender's faster renders and far superior texturing tools, so stick with it.

(Note, this process works better on smaller processing rigs if it is repeated for every character individually. Additionally, since, ATM, diffio doesn't have a way to ignore invisible meshes, you'll just have to save the characters out one at a time. This is the price of a less powerful rig. If you have a scene of just simple meshes, you can export those as a unit.)

First set up your character with all its clothes, textures, and accessories- don't bother posing at this point.

Save your file

Go to *File > Export to Blender*

Now, in Blender, import the file through the diffio program as you already know how to do.

As you're already aware, the resulting mesh will be exploded with it's geometry and armatures all over the place. Ignore this issue, you will soon be deleting most of this material anyway.

Go to the imported collection and note how many objects it is composed of. Now, make that many planes- just planes, empties should probably work too- and title those planes things that make sense like- hat, hair, Susan, shoes etc, etc.

Put those planes in a collection and title it appropriately- I recommend naming it after your character.

Now, go to the shoes plane and link it's materials to the shoes from DAZ- do this for all imported objects, shirt to shirt, susans to susan, etc, etc.

Delete the imported collection.

Congrats, you have now set up a DAZ character in Blender!

"What? How? I just have a bunch of planes!" Those planes are the key and all you really need. Now you can pose your charater any way you want in DAZ, export it as an obj and link the materials on those planes to the appropriate geometry and- poof, you will have perfectly captured a posed DAZ model in Blender.

The downside to this method is the number of steps. The upside is that the .obj format will extract poses from Studio precisely as you see them, morphs, pose, adjustments, location, size- everything.

Even if you do figure out how to properly rig a DAZ model in Blender, much of the rigging of the conforming clothing won't work properly. (With obj do remember to export at 1% size do write surfaces and do NOT write polylines or normals as that will increase your file size by 50% for no reason.) All you have to do is link the materials when they're in Blender. As a bonus, you can modify DAZ materials in Blender if they're not made specifically for a model, using object and boxed mapping. (Do remember to regularly clean your Blender file.)

Comment: To anyone who is aware, YES, there is a program on the daz forums called Sagan alembic that expedites this exact process with smaller file sizes, but, at the moment, it's a little buggy so I can't recommend it. It often auto links materials improperly and there's no way to fix it in Blender when it does.
Do give the creator some love though as once he does get it right, it can port animations as well, which OBJ can't so- this is a BIG DEAL
https://www.daz3d.com/forums/discussion/428856/sagan-a-daz-to-blender-alembic-exporter